# Angular Datatable integration

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I am new to the Angular and I have worked in Datatable (jQuery). Here is my problem, did you know how to integrate jQuery Datatable plugin with Angular6?

My project going to depend fully on the Datatable but i don't find anything to integrate with Angular6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have found (PrimeNg) which is more similar to the jQuery Datatable.

```
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table
```

This has all the basic feature that jQuery Datatable has,

1. Pagination
2. Sorting
3. Table info
4. Search for all columns
5. Inline Edit / Add / Delete
6. Column Show / Hide feature.
7. Expand rows.
8. Table Row selection.

And more than that it is made with pure Angular and It is supporting the latest version (Angular 6). And fully customizable.

So we have decided to go with this one.

Answer (score 2):

1)
Using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) will give you better UI than any other library

2)You can go for [Angular Datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) in this you have to install many packages to achieve datatable all things that to be done is given in this documentation

Comment: My personal experience would advise against using Angular Datatables if you're working with reloading data. It's a mess all around and I could not get it to work properly in two weeks. There were many, many issues with rerendering tables, double data, warnings I could not get rid of, and so on. Better to use Angular Material tables (which may not look professional enough) or one of the other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use material [Angular Material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jquery with angular6. If you use angular forget jquery completly. It's like you want to play basketball in a soccer game. There are other grid implementations for angular which work fine in angular. Never ever include jquery in your angular project.

- Devexpress extreme
- Angular Material

Answer (score 0):

In our project we are using [Ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable), it has a good documentation and a lot of features.